# lagrange multipliers fails

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am looking for a certain counter example. Assume a $C^1$ function $f$ is to be optimized with respect to a $C^1$ constraint $g=0$, and we have at a point $(x,y)$, the existence of a lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ with
$$
\begin{align}
&\nabla f(x,y)=\lambda\nabla g(x,y)\\
&\nabla g(x,y)\neq0\\
\end{align}
$$
But $f$ fails to have an extremum at this point with respect to $g=0$

thanks

Comment: But the extremum occurs at (0,0).. where g has a singular point.. so this is not a counter example.

Comment: You're right, it's a maximum. OK, let me find something else then. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: How about $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3$ and $g(x,y)=x$?

Comment: @Raskolnikov This $g$ doesn't define a compact manifold, hence you can't apply Lagrange method.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: I don't remember that being a necessary condition? Are we talking about the same theorem by the way?

Comment: Do you think there is also an example where the gradient of f is also non-zero?

Comment: @Raskolnikov The existence of the point $\vec x$ and Lagrange multipliers $\vec \lambda$ doesn't guarantee that this point is a solution of optimisation problem, it's only a necessary condition. One of sufficient conditions is that $\{g\}$ defines a compact manifold. Thus applying Lagrange method to your example is pointless.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: But that was the entire point of OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x,y):=x^3+y$ and $g(x,y):=y$. Then $\nabla f(0,0)=\nabla g(0,0)=(0,1)$, but $f(x,0)-f(0,0)=x^3$ assumes both signs in the immediate neighborhood of $(0,0)$.